# Creating Connect Four In Javascript: Looping Buttons to Make a Grid (?)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, button, newline

I am trying to make a Connect 4 (two player) game. I want to make this easy, so I am using a `for` loop (if this is not a good way, or you recommend a different way, please tell me) to make an 8x8 grid (code is below). However, I cant seem to make the buttons be at a new line (every 8 buttons). Here is my code:

```
for(let a=0; a<9; a++){
  for(let b=0; b<8; b++){
    var button = document.createElement("button")
    button.id='button'+i
    button.innerText = "";
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){/* code here */})
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    i++
  }
  var newline = document.createElement("button")
  newline.id='newline'
  newline.innerText = "0";
  newline.addEventListener("click", function(){getStatus()})
  document.body.appendChild(newline);
  newline.style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
  i++
}
```

How do I position the 8th button so that it is on the next line?

Another question I have is about the game mechanisms. If I use a loop, how do I make the buttons' ids so that I can control the buttons that are pressed (so that I can change the ID of the button that is pressed to be a different id). 
Thanks!

Comment: Check the console... `i is not defined`.

Comment: The best way would be to use a grid of elements with styles to set it up.  A table or flexbox grid would both work.  If it's just adding a newline, you can use the `<br>` element.  I'd advise putting a full working demo here in a snippet to get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)     You can create and append an `<br/>` element after the 8 button loop.
2)     I guess u need something like [x, y] matrix of buttons, for example id = "button_x_y". When u click on button it will check the Y value of it and then go through the elements with pace of Y, then change their behavior or IDs

```
button_1_4
button_2_4
button_3_4
button_4_4
...
```

```js
var i = 0;

function moveObjects(pace){

        var a = 0,
            interval = setInterval(function(){ // make a function which runs every 1 sec
                document.getElementById('button_'+ a +`_`+ pace).style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
                
                if(a>0){
                    document.getElementById('button_'+ (a-1) +`_`+ pace).style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; // clearing the traced blocks
                }

                if (a < 8) {
                    a++
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval) //exit from setTimeout if last element was choosed
                };

            }, 1000);
}

for(let a=0; a<9; a++){

  for(let b=0; b<8; b++){

    var button = document.createElement("button")
    button.id='button_'+a+`_`+b // creating x_y matrix
    button.innerText = "";

    button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let pace = e.target.id.substr(-1); //getting the pace of matrix blocks
            moveObjects(pace);
    })

    document.body.appendChild(button);
    i++
  }

  var newline = document.createElement("button")

  newline.id='newline'
  newline.innerText = "0";
  newline.addEventListener("click", function(){getStatus()})
  document.body.appendChild(newline);
  newline.style.pageBreakAfter = "always";

  let _br = document.createElement("br"); //creating block named line break
  document.body.appendChild(_br); //then append it after whatever you want

  i++
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in your code (`i` isn't defined).

You also don't want to be creating a new button to represent a new line. The element you're probably looking for is `<br>` (i.e. line break).

Here's an example showing what I mean:

I also stuck the variable `i` inside the button text so you can see what it looks like, and stopped it incrementing on the "a" `for` loop.

```js
var i = 0;
for (let a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button")
    button.id = 'button' + i
    button.innerText = i;
    button.addEventListener("click", function() { /* code here */ })
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    i++
  }
  var newline = document.createElement("br") // this is the big change
  newline.id = 'newline'
  newline.innerText = "0";
  newline.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getStatus()
  })
  document.body.appendChild(newline);
  newline.style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```